# Staking locking vs reserving

Tags: runtime, staking, pallet-staking, reserved-balance

I am trying to understand why locking a balance is used instead of reserving when staking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locks can overlap, while reserved values cannot. This means that if a value is reserved, it cannot be used in other operations that would also reserve.

Consider somebody who both stakes and participates in democracy - with both operations locking the balance, it means that you can use bonded values to vote with.

If this was reserved, you would lose the ability to vote with bonded balances.